# Analysing a png (1bit color) for pixel

Tags: python, image-processing, png

Today I want to know how I analyse a png image with 1 bit color depth (100*30) pixel.

The pixels in the image are numbered 0..99 for the first row, 100..199 for the second row etc. White pixels represent ascii codes. The ascii code for a particular white pixel is equal to the offset from the last white pixel. For example, the first white pixel at location 65 would represent ascii code 65 ('A'), the next at location 131 would represent ascii code (131 - 65) = 66 ('B') and so on.

The text contained in the image is what i need to encoded in Morse, where "a test" would be encoded as ".- / - . ... -"

[image: This is the picture]

Well, I hope you can help me ;)

Comment: I see two different tasks: 1. extract text from a png image 2. encode text in a morse code alphabet. Good luck with that. It is best to show your effort first and let the community help you. It is also better to split the question into two questions when you decide to show what you've got.

Comment: Yea the problem is.. I can't extract that text into my program. I'm using Pypng the first time and i can't get my Reader work. :/

Comment: FWIW, when you decode that image according to the specs in the 2nd paragraph you get a string of Morse code, i.e., dashes, dots and spaces. And when you translate that Morse into text you get a cryptic string of letters and numbers commencing with  `KQZG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to extract text that's been encoded into an image as per the specification in your question. To extract the image data I'm using PIL (really [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/)).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from PIL import Image

def extract_text(iname):
    last = 0
    chars = []
    for i, v in enumerate(bytearray(Image.open(iname).tobytes())):
        if v:
            chars.append(chr(i - last))
            last = i
    return ''.join(chars)

print extract_text('coded.png')
```

**output**

```
-.- --.- --.. --. -. ..--- .---- .. .-.. -
```

I'll let you write the Morse-decoding stuff. :)